# How to add jQuery to Magento 1 email templates

Tags: email-templates, jquery, order-email

Is it possible to add jQuery to Magento 1 email templates? I would like to modify some text in email templates with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it would be possible to add `<script>` tags to your email template but it's honestly not worth bothering. Your JS is just going to get blocked in the majority of clients.

See:

- https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email#Do-Not-Use *(generic advice from a respected company whose bread and butter is email)*
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/#four *(see Scripting in Emails)*
- https://www.thoughtco.com/javascript-and-emails-2037682
- https://litmus.com/community/discussions/4795-using-javascript-for-emails-in-browser-view